# How to Edit templates in Asp.Net using Radeditor?

Tags: asp.net, radeditor

Im a Software Developer currently working in NCPL.. Here i've a problem regarding Editing of templates at different positions..

We have a ASP.net software where in we sent emails to clients on various occasions. For those events we select templates and edit the data or image in it and send it to our clients.. The problem over here is that i've took a radeditor component and tried to insert a template in it. But unable to edit it at different positions programmatically.. So i request you to kindly clear my issue as soon as possible..
                                   I'm also attaching a demo image for your reference.
Awaiting for your reply...

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by "But unable to edit it at different positions programmatically.."

The content area of RadEditor is a standard editable iframe/div and if you are able to implement your scenario with an editable div, you will be able to achieve it with RadEditor too.